Rank of confluent vandermonde matrix and complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials
While doing some research I've stumbled upon this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2x_0 & 3x_0^2 & \dots  & nx_0^{n-1} \\
    1 & 2x_1 & 3x_1^2 & \dots  & nx_1^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & 2x_n & 3x_n^2 & \dots  & nx_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
which is an confluent vandermonde matrix
Question: Is it true that it's rank is n?
I've tried to put the matrix, for small values of n, to it's row echelon form and it seems that it can be reduced to:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2x_0 & 3x_0^2 & \dots  & nx_0^{n-1} \\
    1 & 2x_1 & 3x_1^2 & \dots  & nx_1^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & 2x_n & 3x_n^2 & \dots  & nx_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} & \sim
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2h_1(x_0) & 3h_2(x_0) & \dots  & nh_n(x_0) \\
    0 & 2 & 3h_1(x_0,x_1) & \dots  & nh_{n-1}(x_0,x_1) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & n
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
by repeatedly subtracting $i$th row from $j$th row where, $j < i$, and dividing by $x_j-x_i$, yet I can't find a way to prove it. What's more, if that seems to be the case, then it shows that
$
\begin{align*}
\frac{h_n(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1},x_k) - h_n(x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{k-1}, x_{k+1})}{x_k-x_{k+1}} = h_{n-1}(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{k_1},x_k,x_{k+1})
\end{align*}$
which also works for the values of $n$ and $k$ that I've checked

write it as the product of a Vandermonde matrix and a diagonal matrix

Assume that the $x_i$'s are distinct, one can do a similar trick as with Vandermonde matrix:
Consider the following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2x_0 & 3x_0^2 & \dots  & nx_0^{n-1} \\
    1 & 2x_1 & 3x_1^2 & \dots  & nx_1^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & 2x_{n-2} & 3x_{n-2}^2 & \dots  & nx_{n-2}^{n-1}\\
    1 & 2X & 3X^2 & \dots  & nX^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
The determinant of this matrix is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ which is zero whenever $X=x_i$ for $0\leq i\leq n-2$ so we deduce that is of the form:
$$\lambda\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}{X-x_i}.$$
By developing the determinant along the last row and identifying the coefficient of the terms of highest degree a quick recursion shows that $\lambda$ is equal to $n!$.
Hence we get that the determinant is non zero when $X=x_{n-1}$. So we have an invertible submatrix of size $n\times n$ which means that the rank is at least $n$. As it is also atmost $n$, we deduce equality.

I assumed you meant, "is the rank equal to $n$ when the $x_i$'s are distincts ?", if it isn't the case the answer is no in general (for example when they are all equal and $n\geq1$). I also found it weird that the matrix is not square, maybe you meant to stop at $x_{n-2}$ ?
